# Pivoting A Column in Pandas based on groups and dynamic column names

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame in python pandas as follows:
      ( the first two columns, mygroup1 & mygroup2 are groupby columns)

```
  df = 

 **mygroup1  mygroup2   tname       @dt      @num   @vek**

   a         p          alpha        may      6       a
   b         q          alpha        june     8       b
   c         r          beta         may      9       c
   d         s          beta         june     11      d
```

I want to pivot the table (the values in tname column) which should be the following with names of columns joined with tname values taken from the other columns (@dt,@num and @vec)

```
 **mygroup1  mygroup2    alpha@dt    alpha@num    alpha@vec    beta@dt  beta@num  beta@vec**
    a         p           may            6            a           nan     nan        nan
    b         q           june           8            b            nan    nan        nan
    c         r           nan            nan        nan            may     9          c
    d         s            nan           nan        nan            june    11         d
```

I am trying to do a pivot using pandas pivot table but not able to get in the below format which I really want. I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
new_df = df.set_index(['mygroup1','mygroup2','tname']).unstack('tname')
new_df.columns = [f'{y}{x}' for x,y in new_df.columns]
new_df = new_df.sort_index(axis=1).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  mygroup1 mygroup2 alpha@dt  alpha@num alpha@vek beta@dt  beta@num beta@vek
0        a        p      may        6.0         a     NaN       NaN      NaN
1        b        q     june        8.0         b     NaN       NaN      NaN
2        c        r      NaN        NaN       NaN     may       9.0        c
3        d        s      NaN        NaN       NaN    june      11.0        d
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Quang! I got most of the part except the function 'f' you put inside in the column creation. What is it called and what is doing exactly. I have never seen that! Thanks again

Comment: It’s called f-string and is similar as the format function, available in Python 3+